# How to connect a HTML <img> with PHP function?

Tags: javascript, php

Been having trouble displaying an avatar for my website. I store all of them in a custom folder called images, where either I or the users create them. The avatar shows only if youre the exact id the avatar is named after. Example:

I have a user who's id is 1, I also have an image with a name 1.png, so this PHP code block gets the link where the images are stored at, fetches the users id and then searches the page for that image that is name after the id.

Here's the code block I've been having issues with:

```
<img id='avatar' 
     class='Avatar'
     src='https:/mysitelink.com/images/' + <?php echo"" . $fetchuser->id . ""; ?>.png?r=<?php echo "$RefreshRate"; ?>' 
     height='350'
     width='350'
     onerror="this.src='mysitelink.com/images/default.png'" />
```

The mysitelink.com is inserted by me to hide the link of the website.

Comment: `src='https:/mysitelink.com/images/' +` erm - your HTML is broken.

Comment: What do you mean by broken? Like really invalid that I have to redo it or something else?

Comment: It *looks* like you're doing some kind of weird JS string concatenation in HTML, which doesn't make sense... it should just be `src='https://mysitelink.com/images/<?= $fetchuser->id; ?>.png?r=<?= $RefreshRate; ?>' ...` (or something along those lines).

Comment: Protocol requires two `//`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below :

```
<img id='avatar' 
     class='Avatar'
     src='https://mysitelink.com/images/<?php echo $fetchuser->id.'.png'; ?>?r=<?php echo "$RefreshRate"; ?>' 
     height='350'
     width='350'
     onerror="this.src='mysitelink.com/images/default.png'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of  `src='https:/mysitelink.com/images/' + <?php echo  . $fetchuser->id . ""; ?>.png?r=<?php echo "$RefreshRate"; ?>'`

try

```
  echo "src='https:/mysitelink.com/images/" . $fetchuser->id . ".png?r=" .$RefreshRate ."'>";
```

Comment: Now it says: Syntax Error, unexpected '='

Comment: What context does that error generate? Do you see it in your console or..? Make sure to  wrap the `echo` part in a PHP block in HTML (e.g. <?php echo ... ?>) @Alex

Comment: yiu just missed  some double quote